# How to capture back button of the browser without using pushstate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, back-button

I have tried capturing the back button action on the browser using pushstate and popstate but problem is pushstate alters the history, thus affecting the normal functioning of back button.

Answer (score 0):

Most people recommend using:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    if (window.innerDocClick) {
        window.innerDocClick = false;
    } else {
        if (window.location.hash != '#undefined') {
            goBack();
        } else {
            history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
            location.reload();
        }
    }
}
function goBack() {
    window.location.hash = window.location.lasthash[window.location.lasthash.length-1];
    //blah blah blah
    window.location.lasthash.pop();
}
```

Comment: I dont have any hash in my url.

Comment: you can also goBack in else part

Answer (score 0):

Create an Array that collects the window.location.hash of the user with every change made to window.location.lasthash.

```
const updateHistory = (curr) => {
    window.location.lasthash.push(window.location.hash);
    window.location.hash = curr;
}
```

Unfortunately, there's no native event fired for clicking the browser's back button. However, there is a nice method to faking it using a combination of other native event listeners.

First, set a boolean that gets toggled each time the document is rendered by listening for the `onmouseover` event.

```
const onDocRenderHandler = (bool) => {
    window.innerDocClick = bool;
}

document.onmouseover = onDocRenderHandler(true)
```

After the user clicks the back button, the document again renders so set the boolean flag to toggle again; only this time listening for the `onmouseleave` event to fire.

```
document.onmouseleave = onDocRenderHandler(false)
```

Finally, listen for the`onhashchange` event to fire in between document renders. This simulates a pseudo back button event for us to listen and act on.

```
const onHashChangeHandler = () => {
    if(!window.innerDocClick) {
        history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
        location.reload();
    }
}
window.onhashchange = onHashChangeHandler()
```

Comment: Check the `updateHistory` function expression I list first. There's where your hash is set.